# Passing State of App.js to Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, react-props

I'm working on the main page of a website and I'd like to have a specific nav/menu bar for the main page and a different one for the other components (the main page hides de "home" button and the others show it).

The issue I have at the moment is that the logic of rendering this menu lives on App and I'm having a hard time to find the proper way to pass the state of my App component to the other components, probably just because of the lack of experience.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./main";
import MapContainer from "./mapcontainer";
import Venue from "./venue";
import Schedule from "./schedule";
import Accommodation from "./accommodation";
import Couple from "./couple";
import Honeymoon from "./honeymoon";
import Uploader from "./uploader";
import Friday from "./friday";
import Saturday from "./saturday"
import Sunday from "./sunday";
import Dresscode from "./dresscode";

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            error: false,
            isHome: true
        };        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("App mounted");
    }


    render() {

        function HomeComponentMenu(props) {
            return (
                <nav className="header-on-app">
                    <button>Contact Us</button>
                    <button className="logout-btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></button>
                </nav>
            );
        }

        function AllOtherComponentsMenu(props) {
            return (
                <nav className="header-on-app">
                    <button><Link to="/">Home</Link></button>
                    <button>Contact Us</button>
                    <button className="logout-btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></button>
                </nav>
            );
        }

        const isHome = this.state.isHome;
        let menu;

        if (isHome) {
            menu = <HomeComponentMenu/>;
        } else {
            menu = <AllOtherComponentsMenu/>;
        }

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>

              <nav className="header-on-app">{menu}</nav>
                <div className="app-container">     
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                    <Route exact path="/venue" component={Venue}/>
                    <Route exact path="/venuemap" component={MapContainer}/>
                    <Route exact path="/schedule" component={Schedule}/>
                    <Route exact path="/accommodation" component={Accommodation}/>
                    <Route exact path="/couple" component={Couple}/>
                    <Route exact path="/honeymoon" component={Honeymoon}/>
                    <Route exact path="/uploader" component={Uploader} />
                    <Route exact path="/friday" component={Friday} />
                    <Route exact path="/saturday" component={Saturday} />
                    <Route exact path="/sunday" component={Sunday} />
                    <Route exact path="/dresscode" component={Dresscode} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

**Component I'd like to set isHome to false**

```
import MapContainer from "./mapcontainer";


export default class Venue extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            error:false,
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="venue-container">

            <h1>Anna & Rodolfo</h1>
            <h2><span>_______</span> Venue . Local . Veranstalungsort <span>_______</span></h2>
            {this.state.error && <h2 className="error">Ops! Something went wrong.</h2>}

            <div className="grid-container-venue">


                    <div className="item">
                    <img src="venue.png" alt="Avatar" className="image"/> 
                    <div className="background-grid-items">
                    <div className="text-address">
                    <a href="https://www.g71972,15z/data=!4887b!8m2!3d52.47094!4d12.71972">
                        <p>Kulturschloss</p>
                        <p>Abcd.30 3456 Berlin </p>
                        <p>Germany . Alemanha . Deutschland</p>
                    </a>    
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="item">
                    <img src="website.png" alt="Avatar" className="image"/> 
                    <div className="background-grid-items">
                    <div className="text">
                    <a href="https://www.kult.de/">   
                        <p>To the Website</p>
                        <p>Para o Website</p>
                        <p>Zur Website</p>
                    </a>    
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="item">
                    <img src="transportation.png" alt="Avatar" className="image"/>    
                    <div className="background-grid-items">
                    <div className="text">
                        <p>Transportation</p>
                        <p>Traslado</p>
                        <p>Transport</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="item">
                        <div className="background-grid-venue">
                            <div className="map">
                            <MapContainer/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Since my components are being rendered by React Router, I tried to render props passing it in an inline function and afterwards pass along to the argument I was creating, but somehow it didn't work. Would you have any suggestions on how to solve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To pass a state to a child component, you have to pass it as props of the child component.

e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import TableView from './TableView'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    item: 'this is the item'
  }

render() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/home">
        <TableView itemList={this.state.item}></TableView>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  )
}

}
```

to get the props in the child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class TableView extends Component {
  render(){
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.props.item}
    </React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

EDIT:
It would also help to debug if you have the react devtools addons in your browser to check if the values of the state of each component

Answer (score 0):

To pass props to a react route you have to define it in the render function like this:

`<Route exact path="/venue" render={(props) => <Venue updateHomeState={this.updateHomeState}/>}/>`

To alter the isHome state on the parent, you could define that function on the parent like:

```
updateHomeState = (newState) => { 
    this.setState({ isHome: newState }) 
}
```

And then call it in `componentDidMount()` of your child component like `this.props.updateHomeState(newState)`.

Comment: thank you very much! It works well at first. The Main page has the navbar I'd like to have and when I go to the Venue page, I can see the new nav bar containing the "Home" button. The only issue is that when I click on the button and I'm redirected back to the Main Page, the navbar is updated and the "Home" button is back there again. I'm going to have a look now and try to change the behaviour, but thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :) I've updated my answer to show how you could pass that same function to different components and have them affect the `isHome` state in different ways. You could pass it to the `main` component in the same way and call it with `true` instead of `false` like you would in the child components.

Comment: Thank you again, @Lazarus! I'm pretty sure that your solution will be very helpful!